# How to change key name using JoltTransformJSON in Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Pls help with this jolt transformation.

Note:

- If there is field `"ServiceFamily"` then change the field name to
  `"tag1"`
- If there is field `"PublisherName"` then change the field name to
  `"tag2"`

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "ServiceFamily": "Compute",
    "CostAllocationRuleName": null,
    "benefitId": null,
    "benefitName": null
  },
  {
    "PublisherName": "Microsoft",
    "ChargeType": "Usage",
    "Frequency": "UsageBased",
    "PricingModel": "OnDemand",
    "benefitName": null
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "Tag1": "Compute",
    "CostAllocationRuleName": null,
    "benefitId": null,
    "benefitName": null
  },
  {
    "Tag2": "Microsoft",
    "ChargeType": "Usage",
    "Frequency": "UsageBased",
    "PricingModel": "OnDemand",
    "benefitName": null
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use such a **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ServiceFamily": "[#2].Tag1",
        "PublisherName": "[#2].Tag2",
        "*": "[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Alternatively you can use the following one which consecutively applies **modify** and **remove** transformation specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Tag1": "=(@(1,ServiceFamily))",
        "Tag2": "=(@(1,PublisherName))"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ServiceFamily": "",
        "PublisherName": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]